How to Update a Table in Notion Page Using Notion API with Row Filtering Based on ENV Value?
I'm trying to find a way to use the Notion API to update or patch a table in a Notion page. Specifically, I want to filter the rows in the table based on the Env column value, and then update the Last Deployed, Deployed By, and Branch Deploy columns for that row.
Here is what my table looks like in Notion:

I tried using the following API to filter rows based on the Env column value:
QUERY_RESPONSE=$(curl -s -X POST "https://api.notion.com/v1/databases/$NOTION_DATABASE_ID/query" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $NOTION_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Notion-Version: 2022-06-28" \
  -d '{
    "filter": {
      "property": "Env",
      "rich_text": {
        "equals": "'"$ENVIRONMENT"'"
      }
    }
  }')

However, I think this might be incorrect because I’m using the API endpoint for querying a database, but my table is actually located within a page, not a database. I need help finding the right API and approach to filter and update specific rows in a table that’s within a page.
Question:
How can I filter and update rows in a table located within a Notion page, rather than a database?
What would be the correct API and approach for this use case?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.
